# Android - make captured image smaller

Tags: android, android-camera

I capture image by default camera software and I get saved my image into some directory to local memory. My question is, is there any way how to make this picture smaller? I will need to send it via internet connection to server, that's why it has to be VGA on maximum. I know there is way to write my own photo part of an app, but I thinks it is nice to use default and then some method for making the picture smaller. I just haven't figured out, how. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.tmp"););
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4; //subsampling

        int compress = 75;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, compress, new FileOutputStream(file));
```

It's dirty example. Use try catch, null check etc.

Comment: Thanks and how for the is, it should be the imput stream so I should read image dest from input stream?

Comment: Sorry I've forgot it. Yes, it's InputStream.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question, when I try to open this picture in Android phone, I can't, but in PC there is everything OK. Do you know, where will be the problem?

Comment: How do you opening this picture Android phone?

Comment: Just in default file explorer. I see thumbnail. It has e.g. 70kb (muste be read instantly) and I wait, even more than 10, 15 sec, than the picture in full res appears on the screen. Huh, don't know whats the problem...

Comment: I don't know. That's problem on a photo browser side.